# How to desaturate an image using Emgu c#

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I know that we desaturate an image by decreasing the values in the Saturation channel. I want to acomplish this using **c#** with **emgu**

For instance here is **c++** code using **opencv** to do so:

```
Mat Image = imread("images/any.jpg");
// Specify scaling factor
float saturationScale = 0.01;

Mat hsvImage;
// Convert to HSV color space
cv::cvtColor(Image,hsvImage,COLOR_BGR2HSV);

// Convert to float32
hsvImage.convertTo(hsvImage,CV_32F);

vector<Mat>channels(3);
// Split the channels
split(hsvImage,channels);
// Multiply S channel by scaling factor 
channels[1] = channels[1] * saturationScale;

// Clipping operation performed to limit pixel values 
// between 0 and 255
min(channels[1],255,channels[1]);
max(channels[1],0,channels[1]);

// Merge the channels 
merge(channels,hsvImage);

// Convert back from float32
hsvImage.convertTo(hsvImage,CV_8UC3);

Mat imSat;
// Convert to BGR color space
cv::cvtColor(hsvImage,imSat,COLOR_HSV2BGR);

// Display the images
Mat combined;
cv::hconcat(Image, imSat, combined);
namedWindow("Original Image   --   Desaturated Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
```

In c# I have:

```
var img = new Image<Gray, byte>("images/any.jpg");
var imhHsv = img.Convert<Hsv, byte>();
var channels = imhHsv.Split();
// Multiply S channel by scaling factor and clip (limit)
channels[1] = (channels[1] * saturationScale);
```

I am not sure how to merge modified saturation channel with `imHsv`, if I do this:

```
CvInvoke.Merge(channels, imhHsv);
```

there is error:

> cannot convert 'Emgu.CV.Image[]' to
>   'Emgu.CV.IInputArrayOfArrays'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put a `VectorOfMat` into the `CvInvoke.Merge` and it works.

```
Mat[] m = new Mat[3];
m[0] = CvInvoke.CvArrToMat(channels[0]);
m[1] = CvInvoke.CvArrToMat(channels[1]);
m[2] = CvInvoke.CvArrToMat(channels[2]);

VectorOfMat vm = new VectorOfMat(m);

CvInvoke.Merge(vm, imhHsv);
```